# Why does it take a long time to import a module in a different thread when the main thread is running an infinite loop?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.4

I have the following Python code:

```
import threading
from datetime import datetime
import time

def f():
    print('---- {:%H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.now()))
    import http.server
    print('---- {:%H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.now()))

threading.Thread(target=f).start()

while True:
    pass
```

When I execute it, I see a great deal of time being consumed to `import http.server`. As you can see from the following output it took 23 seconds for the import to occur.

```
C:\>python foo.py
---- 10:12:03
---- 10:12:26
```

However, if I put a little sleep in the infinite `while` loop, the import happens faster.

```
import threading
from datetime import datetime
import time

def f():
    print('---- {:%H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.now()))
    import http.server
    print('---- {:%H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.now()))

threading.Thread(target=f).start()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Output:

```
C:\>python foo.py
---- 10:15:58
---- 10:15:58
```

I know the usage of `join()` method but I want to know precisely why does it take so long to `import http.server` when the infinite `while` loop doesn't have a sleep statement in it.

Comment: Assuming you have little to nothing else running, the reason for this is that the `while True` loop will occur so often and so fast that if you look at it this way, each call in each thread is given the "zipper" principle, every thread get's one CPU cycle before the next thread get's his/her's. So if you're importing a "big" module with lots of code, it will take a while since between each line, one `while True`has to loop and use up a cycle in your processor. (roughly speeking)

Comment: @Torxed it will possibly hog 99,9% of CPU cycles only on the processor's core which CPython interpreter is running on. Other cores are unaffected.

Comment: Quite obviously yes since Python is not developed to run on multiple cores out of the box. This is also something i thought shouldn't need to be explained so I removed that section of my description a long time ago :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CPython uses Global Interpreter Lock to protect interpreter context. This prevents threads from running in the same time. Actually they all run on the single processor core. In CPython you can benefit from threads when they do idle-like operations i.e. waiting for I.O. or listening on the socket.
You gave a lot of work for the main thread. While `pass` does nothing interesting it consumes CPU cycle and also the interpreter believes it's important to give CPU time to this thread.
With `sleep` you say `don't waste anything for this thread until time expires`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on the topic, but as far as I know multiple threads run on same core one after another, so it's a question of CPU time sharing. Then adding sleep to infinite loop would give  your import thread more resources.
To run in parallel use multiprocessing. Then your code will use more than one core.
You can check out this simple [example](http://www.martinkral.sk/blog/2011/03/python-multicore-vs-threading-example/)

Comment: You should also say it's specific for CPython implementation.